# numberOfRowsInSection running in infinite loop

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {     
   int rows;     // Return the number of rows in the section.        
    switch (section)
    {          
         case 0:      
           rows = 1;    
           break;   
         case 1:  
            rows = 3;  
            break;    
         case 2:     
            rows = 2; 
            break;   
         case 3:   
             rows = 1;         
            break;      
         default:  
            rows = 1;         
            break;       
    }     
  return rows;
 }
```

this code is running in infinite loop. for the first it returns right no of rows. but after that starts running on infinite loop. 
and one more thing, why section starts from the highest no and den come to 0 and den in ascending order??

Comment: you want different table-view different section or other ?

Comment: what you have return in numberOfSectionsInTableView:

Comment: @freenalcer: numberOfSectionsInTableView returns 4 sections.

Comment: check where all you are reloading the `tableView`. maybe you have a `-reloadData` or similar somewhere that's causing the table to reload constantly

Answer (score 2):

There is no infinite loop in your code above. It's quite possible that it is being *called* from an infinite loop.

To find this, place a breakpoint in the method, continue a few times (to ensure you're in the loop rather than just the normal calls) and then look at the stack trace on the side. This should give you a pretty clear idea of where the looping is coming from. You are probably calling reloadData from within one of your datasource or delegate methods.

Comment: thats wat m looking for..coz this code is not new for me...still giving this error breaking my application.